# Chaining objects by siblings in javascript

Tags: javascript, chaining, lodash

I have a simple problem, there is an object, which elements have an array of their connections. Only to the siblings:

```
var obj = {
    1: [2],
    2: [1,3],
    3: [2,4],
    4: [3],

    5: [6],
    6: [5]
}
```

There is two connections, the first 4 is connected to each other, and the 5. and 6. too. I would get a list depend on a selected element, about who is connected to each other. So if I select the `giveMeTheListOfSiblingIn(3)`, i would like to get this list: `[1,2,3,4]`.

It's not to difficult, by I can't get the solution, always avoid infinite loop. Here is my trying in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kreestian/5JHXt/), I used the Lo-Dash framework, but you do not have to.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why `3` is in the output of `giveMeTheListOfSiblingIn(3)`?

Comment: It is an example. So if I select one of the elements, I have to get it's siblings. If the parameter 5, I have to get `[5,6]`. If the parameter 1,2,3 or 4, I have to get `[1,2,3,4]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's my suggested solution, with a little modification of the call function's parameters.
Maybe you would like to send obj as a param too.

```
var obj = {
    1: [2],
    2: [1,3],
    3: [2,4],
    4: [3],
    5: [6],
    6: [5]
}
list = [];
function call(id) {

    if (list.indexOf(id) == -1) {
       list.push(id);
       obj[id].forEach(call)
    }
    return list;
}

var result = call(6);

console.log(result);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/9L5s6/1/

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to stuck in a loop and go through all of the siblings, you may want to look at this like at some sort of a `tree`, where your `first visited` node is a `root`. In that case you would use `recursive algorithm` for walking through the tree. However you would need to save visited nodes so that you would not visit them again.

Example:
Lets say you visit 3'rd node first.

```
3 has two connections, visit 2.
2 -> visit 1.
1 points to 2, but 2 is visited so return.
2 (because 2 points to 1) also points to 3, but 3 is visited so return.
3 also points to 4, visit 4.
4 points to 3, 3 is visited so return.
3 no more connections and also a root node so tree walking is complete.
```

Hope this helps :).

Answer (score 0):

```
var obj = {
    1: [2],
    2: [1,3],
    3: [2,4],
    4: [3],

    5: [6],
    6: [5]
}

//initiallly all siblings will be an empty string
var giveMeTheListOfSiblingIn = function(index, allSiblings) {
    //get imidiate or directly connected siblings
    var _mySiblings = obj[index];
    var me = index
    for(var i=0;i<_mySiblings.length;i++) {
        //if sibling is already added, don't add it again
        //ignore already found sibling and sibling of its sibling as its
        //siblings are already capture. See  push line below
        if(allSiblings.indexOf(_mySiblings[i]) == -1 && _mySiblings[i] != me) {
            //push currently found sibling
            allSiblings.push(_mySiblings[i])
            //get siblings of currently found sibling and pass all the siblings found yet
            //so that it will not search again for the same sibling
            allSiblings = giveMeTheListOfSiblingIn(_mySiblings[i], allSiblings)
        }
    }
    return allSiblings
}
```

**Ouput - Test Cases**

```
giveMeTheListOfSiblingIn(2, [])
//output [1, 2, 3, 4]

giveMeTheListOfSiblingIn(6, [])
//output [5, 6]
```